# How to diagnose crashes in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Since recently, my machine started to fail in the following way: Suddenly, the screen turns light blue or white and the machine stops responding to any input (except power off button).

How can I find out, why this happens? E. g. what log file can I look at?

Comment: Stops responding is not a true crash and will not generate a log. It must bluescreen before you get a crash dump log.

Comment: To begin with, you must start by narrowing down if the problem is hardware or software and OS or Application related. Try diagnostic modes like Safe mode and use tools like msconfig, autoruns for the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315263
This will help with diagnosing the issue. 
There is an application called BlueScreenView. Download and run that. It will allow you to see the debugging information, so you can then either post it here or update your question. A quick Google search once you know the code(s) should yield good results; If not just post a question or update your question.